# Jquery Selectors + Syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use a jQuery selector (this) to get an image nested on the same level.
Just a syntax error, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this img).slideUp('fast');
        $(this img.accordionButtonActive).slideDown('fast');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBrhH/

Comment: Check his jsfiddle; it's very comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the effect like this:

[http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/3/)

using:

```
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('img', this).slideUp('fast');
    $('img.accordionButtonActive', this).slideDown('fast');
```

I changed some events too. Try it ;)

Comment: Thanks alot, I like the event changes. 
I was just messing around trying to write an if statement to check for 'on' and show the image/remove other. Thanks for the insight, and initiative!

Comment: And you can make the same with simple code, using [toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). See here the result: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/4/) ;)

Comment: Fixed the class 'on' of the first open accordion by default: [http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/zBrhH/8/)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do $(this img). But you can pass a second parameter which defines the scope, try this:

```
$('img', this)...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(this img).slideUp('fast');
```

should be

```
    $(this).find("img").slideUp('fast');
```

Demo, with working accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/zBrhH/2/